# how to get JsonReader byte to make a percentage

Tags: android, json, gson, rx-java

I need to download Json file with 20k items and in the same time I need to show a percentage in a textview. Now I'm only test the flow of the code so I show simple a log with the current percentage. So I create an Observable and I do it:

```
private void downloadAirports()
{
    final OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

    final Request mRequest = new Request.Builder().url(SERVICE_ENDPOINT).build();

    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber)
        {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream;
                okhttp3.Response response = mOkHttpClient.newCall(mRequest).execute();
                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    inputStream = response.body().byteStream();
                   long len = response.body().contentLength();

                    Log.d("str",String.valueOf(len));

                    String progress = "0";
                    subscriber.onNext(progress);

                    final int bufferSize = 1024;
                    boolean flag = false;
                    final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
                    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
                    Reader in = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");

                    long total = 0;
                    airp = new ArrayList<AirportObject>();
                    int count =0;

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    airp = new ArrayList<>();
                    long i = 0;
                    reader.beginArray();

                    while (reader.hasNext())
                    {

                        AirportObject message = gson.fromJson(reader, AirportObject.class);
                        airp.add(message);
                        i++;
                        byte [] arr = message.toString().getBytes();
                        total = total + arr.length;

                        Log.d("%",String.valueOf(total));

                        double p = total/len * 100;


                        subscriber.onNext(String.valueOf(p));
                    }


                    reader.endArray();
                    reader.close();






                    //airp = Arrays.asList(airportArray);


                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {

                long size, perc;
                public void onCompleted()
                {
                    Log.wtf("on complete","On complete");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(final String progress) {
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                     //       Log.d("%",progress);
                           // textView.setText("Download aeroporti in corso:"+progress+"%");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

but I give two different values to the variable len (the effective number of byte) and the variable total. So how could I get the value of effective byte downloaded from JsonReader in while cycle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rethink your progress model in order to make it more simple and separated apart. What if you encapsulate the progress state into an `InputStream` [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and expose it while reading?

How it could work? First of all you have to encapsulate the real input stream you are going to decorate. Also some intermediate state is needed to count read bytes and compare this value to the expected length value. Once a certain event occurs upon some condition, just fire the ratio value through the subscriber that's already encapsulated. The input stream decorator below uses a `Float` ratio where the values are always in range of `[0;1]`. Why? Let your view decide *how* the *normalized* ratio should be rendered: either percentage in a text view, or a progress bar, or whatever else. Percentage is basically just a human-friendly *unnormalized* value, while giving ratio you make sure you *always* pass `0..1` values and don't care the "user-friendliness" at the generator site (imagine what if someday you will expose promille, hm-m-m -- that would break your code elsewhere that would expect percents rather than promilles).

```java
public final class ProgressInputStream
        extends InputStream {

    private final Subscriber<? super Float> subscriber;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final long expectedLength;
    private final long lengthPerPercent;

    private long actualLength;
    private long currentChunkLength;

    private ProgressInputStream(final Subscriber<? super Float> subscriber, final InputStream inputStream, final long expectedLength) {
        this.subscriber = subscriber;
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
        this.expectedLength = expectedLength;
        lengthPerPercent = (long) ceil((double) expectedLength / 100);
    }

    public static InputStream progressInputStream(final Subscriber<? super Float> subscriber, final InputStream inputStream, final long expectedLength) {
        return new ProgressInputStream(subscriber, inputStream, expectedLength);
    }

    @Override
    public int read()
            throws IOException {
        return (int) count(inputStream.read());
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final byte[] bytes)
            throws IOException {
        return (int) count(inputStream.read(bytes));
    }

    @Override
    public int read(final byte[] bytes, final int offset, final int length)
            throws IOException {
        return (int) count(inputStream.read(bytes, offset, length));
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(final long n)
            throws IOException {
        return count(inputStream.skip(n));
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
            throws IOException {
        inputStream.close();
    }

    private long count(final long read) {
        if ( read != -1 ) {
            if ( actualLength == 0 ) {
                subscriber.onNext(0F);
            }
            currentChunkLength += read;
            actualLength += read;
            if ( currentChunkLength >= lengthPerPercent ) {
                currentChunkLength = 0;
                if ( actualLength < expectedLength ) {
                    subscriber.onNext((float) actualLength / expectedLength);
                } else if ( actualLength == expectedLength ) {
                    subscriber.onNext(1F);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                } else {
                    throw new AssertionError("Must never happen. A bug in the code around?");
                }
            } else if ( actualLength == expectedLength ) {
                subscriber.onNext(1F);
                subscriber.onCompleted();
            }
        }
        return read;
    }

}
```

Now, having the progress calculator encapsulated in the decorator, a typical usage may look as follows:

```java
Observable
        .<Float>create(subscriber -> {
            final File file = new File("/tmp/some.json");
            try ( final InputStream inputStream = progressInputStream(subscriber, new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), file.length());
                  final JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8")) ) {
                reader.beginArray();
                while ( reader.hasNext() ) {
                    gson.<AirportObject>fromJson(reader, AirportObject.class);
                }
                reader.endArray();
            } catch ( final IOException ex ) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        })
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Float>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(final Float ratio) {
                out.printf("Read: %s%%\n", (long) (ratio * 100));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                out.println("Downloaded");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(final Throwable ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });
```

Check out that now you don't have to count the progress while parsing your JSON thus making your code cleaner. Moreover, you can re-use such a stream elsewhere, not just for Gson/etc.

I tested it on a desktop system only, not on a real device (no activities, UI threads or HTTP networking, just a JSON file and stdout output), but the concept can be easily migrated to the Android system with minimum efforts. Here is the output for a file with length of 84047:

> Read: 0%
>   Read: 9%
>   Read: 19%
>   Read: 29%
>   Read: 38%
>   Read: 48%
>   Read: 58%
>   Read: 68%
>   Read: 77%
>   Read: 87%
>   Read: 97%
>   Read: 100%
>   Downloaded

Comment: Why we should use inputStream inside inputStream subclass?